# Why is native .bind() so slow?

Tags: google-chrome, bind

I recently came across this issue. For a project I'm working on, we were using .bind() way too often and it actually hit the performance quite hard considering that we only have 16ms for the rendering loop to do things.

So I did some jsperf and noticed that calling a bound function (besides of the extra garbage) is way slower than calling an unbound function or using .call on a function.

I literally changed every piece of code to avoid bindings and to use .call/.apply instead. Ding this i not only spawned less functions but also increased the performance of my app a great deal.

However, I was unsatisfied with this and wrote a new way of binding functions. 
https://github.com/SebastianNette/FastBind

This is overwriting the native bind method with a .call/.apply approach.
And it runs 96% faster.

Doing some testings on nodejs is came to these results:
Calling a bound function is 20 times slower than calling an unbound function.
Calling a bound function with my own approach takes only 2 times the time of the unbound call.

So I was wondering what is wrong with the native binding function. Why does it behave like that? And which would be the best way to deal with that issue.

Most of my app code is now written like that:

```js
var scope = this;
this.boundFn = function(a,b,c) { return scope.fn(a,b,c); };
```

Or even

```js
this.callback = fn;
this.context = context;

this.callback.call(this.context);
```

I do prefer the latter because it doesn't spawn any new functions. However, sometimes I just do have to bind. (handlers, timers, etc).

Comment: `.call` and `.apply` as I understand it, do something very different with respect to the `this` keyword, and context. If you are avoiding the `this` keyword then you should be okay. Word of warning however, the lambdas you are creating are creating closures, which can leak memory if you aren't careful (the functions have a reference to `scope`).

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is that it makes a clone of the object you are using but replaces the underlying prototype of object. Instead of using a generic precompiled object from the page rendered code it now has to take two things:

The passed variable thats to be come this. analyse it, clone it. then inject the specified function thats to be called into the new object. Then execute the function in the new object. afterwards if no longer called clean it up.

The more complex and more scoping loops an object has the long the bind will take because the engine needs to traverse the scope tree of all functions and parameters to see what needs to be copied.

You are already using scoping, which I strongly advice. It is less memory intense and the engine does not have to copy the objects and then call the functions. And you get the added benefit that you can access properties from both objects.

In my experience binding is never truly needed. Just use setters and getters for properties, otherwise the scoped variables won't always change in the main object.

Take for example this snippet

```js
function domagic() {
    this.myproperty = "Hello ";
  }
domagic.prototype = {
  perform:function(){
    var that = this;
    var hello = "World";
    setTimeout(function(){
                         // this in this contect is whatever runs timeout. not domagic
                         // I use this for jQuery and my own objects to get best
                         // of both worlds, but I always post a comment in a scope 
                         // to remind myself what this and that refers to.
                         window.alert(that.myproperty+hello);
                         that.set("Goodbye ");
                         },2000);
  },
  set : function(what) {
    this.myproperty = what;
  }
};
magic = new domagic();
magic.perform();
setTimeout(function(){magic.perform();},2000);
```